# Process stuck when training on multiple nodes using PyTorch DistributedDataParallel

Tags: deep-learning, parallel-processing, pytorch, distributed

I am trying to run the script `mnist-distributed.py` from [Distributed data parallel training in Pytorch](https://yangkky.github.io/2019/07/08/distributed-pytorch-tutorial.html). I have also pasted the same code here. (I have replaced my actual `MASTER_ADDR` with `a.b.c.d` for posting here).

```py
import os
import argparse
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.distributed as dist

class ConvNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes=10):
        super(ConvNet, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(1, 16, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))
        self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))
        self.fc = nn.Linear(7*7*32, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.layer1(x)
        out = self.layer2(out)
        out = out.reshape(out.size(0), -1)
        out = self.fc(out)
        return out

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-n', '--nodes', default=1, type=int, metavar='N')
    parser.add_argument('-g', '--gpus', default=1, type=int,
                        help='number of gpus per node')
    parser.add_argument('-nr', '--nr', default=0, type=int,
                        help='ranking within the nodes')
    parser.add_argument('--epochs', default=2, type=int, metavar='N',
                        help='number of total epochs to run')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    args.world_size = args.gpus * args.nodes               
    os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = 'a.b.c.d'              
    os.environ['MASTER_PORT'] = '8890'                    
    mp.spawn(train, nprocs=args.gpus, args=(args,))       

def train(gpu, args):
    rank = args.nr * args.gpus + gpu                              
    dist.init_process_group(                                   
        backend='nccl',                                         
        init_method='env://',                                   
        world_size=args.world_size,                              
        rank=rank                                               
    )                                                          
    
    torch.manual_seed(0)
    model = ConvNet()
    torch.cuda.set_device(gpu)
    model.cuda(gpu)
    batch_size = 100
    # define loss function (criterion) and optimizer
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss().cuda(gpu)
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), 1e-4)
    
    # Wrap the model
    model = nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel(model,
                                                device_ids=[gpu])

    # Data loading code
    train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(
        root='./data',
        train=True,
        transform=transforms.ToTensor(),
        download=True
    )                                               
    train_sampler = torch.utils.data.distributed.DistributedSampler(
        train_dataset,
        num_replicas=args.world_size,
        rank=rank
    )

    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        dataset=train_dataset,
       batch_size=batch_size,
       shuffle=False,            
       num_workers=0,
       pin_memory=True,
      sampler=train_sampler)     

    total_step = len(train_loader)
    for epoch in range(args.epochs):
        for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
            images = images.cuda(non_blocking=True)
            labels = labels.cuda(non_blocking=True)
            # Forward pass
            outputs = model(images)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

            # Backward and optimize
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            if (i + 1) % 100 == 0 and gpu == 0:
                print('Epoch [{}/{}], Step [{}/{}], Loss: {:.4f}'.format(
                    epoch + 1, 
                    args.epochs, 
                    i + 1, 
                    total_step,
                    loss.item())
                   )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

There are 2 nodes with 2 GPUs each. I run this command from the terminal of the master node-

> python mnist-distributed.py -n 2 -g 2 -nr 0

, and then this from the terminal of the other node-

> python mnist-distributed.py -n 2 -g 2 -nr 1

But then my process gets stuck with no output on either terminal.

Running the same code on a single node using the following command works perfectly fine-

> python mnist-distributed.py -n 1 -g 2 -nr 0

Answer (score 1):

I met a similar problem. And the problem is solved by

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

Edit it:

```
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""                           <----- Original commented
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft"           <------ Change
```

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot to see the change.

Ref: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1637#issuecomment-338268158